# Mirror image of a binary tree

Tags: c++, tree

I wrote a small routines to create a mirror for any binary tree. I am just sharing my necessary routines instead of full class. could you please let me know your comments on this. I just curious to find the complexity of this but I am new to algorithms.

```
void tree_sample::mirror_image()
{
    create_mirror_for_left_subtree(root->left);
    create_mirror_for_right_subtree(root->right);
    tree_node* temp = 0;
    if(root->left)
        temp = root->left;
    root->left = root->right;
    if(temp)
        root->right = temp;
    else
        root->right = NULL;     
}

void tree_sample::create_mirror_for_left_subtree(tree_node *temp)
{
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        do_mirror_for_inidividual_node(temp);
        temp = temp->left;
    }
}

void tree_sample::create_mirror_for_right_subtree(tree_node *temp)
{
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        do_mirror_for_inidividual_node(temp);
        temp = temp->right;
    }
}

void tree_sample::do_mirror_for_inidividual_node(tree_node *temp)
{
    tree_node* temp2 = 0;
    if(temp->left)
        temp2 = temp->left;
    temp->left = temp->right;
    if(temp2)
        temp->right = temp2;
    else
        temp->right= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have over complicated things and I don't think it works for the generic tree (as your `create_mirror_for_[left|right]_subtree()` only recurse down one side of the tree.

Why the test before a swap?

```
tree_node* temp = 0;
if(root->left)
    temp = root->left;    // If left is NULL you can still assign it 
                          // to temp and get the same result.
root->left = root->right;
if(temp)
    root->right = temp;
else
    root->right = NULL;   // If temp is null you could just assign
                          // it to right then both sides of the branch
                          // are identical and they collapse into a
                          // single statement.

// Much easier to write as:
tree_node* temp = root->left;
root->left      = root->right;
root->right     = temp;

// Which of course can be replaced by std::swap
std::swap(root->left, root->right);
```

I assume you want to swap all nodes in the tree (otherwise it's not a mirror).

```
class Tree
{
    public:
        void mirrorTree()
        {
            root.mirrorTree(root);
        }
    private:
        void mirrorTree(Node* node)
        {
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            using std::swap;
            swap(node->left, node->right);
            mirrorTree(node->left);
            mirrorTree(node->right);
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Loki Astari. You are right. I missed to cover the left chileof right subtree and right child of left subtrees. Your code wil cover all the nodes i guess. But is there a way that i can do it in iteration itself rather than using recursion? how can i cover all nodes using loops than being recursive?

Comment: @funwithlinx: Yes there is. Look up breadth first traversal of a tree.